# Use Vault with Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is it possible to store credit card information from the user then use the stored token/info with adaptive payments to payout sellers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the Vault operation in the REST API, then unfortunately, no, it is not possible to use the stored credit card information in Adaptive Payment. Both operations are from different API family (REST API and Adaptive Payment API), so they are not compatible.

However, in Adaptive Payment, there is Preapproval operation which allows storing payer's payment information to be used in future payment (similar to Vault/ Reference Transaction/Tokenization). Credit card payment can be done through guest checkout feature (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#guest-payments) but if I am not mistaken, there are limitations.

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#preapproved-payments-flow