# Saving credit card without PCI compliance

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to implement PayPal Adaptive Payments with Simple Payments and store credit card for later use. I've discovered that this is the easiest way to charge the customer for all the fees that might have happened during a transaction and do it after the transaction has been successful.

[Apparently their API supports storing credit cards](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_savedcard/ruby?interactive=ON&env=sandbox) but requires sending credit card data to their servers. In doing so my server would have to be PCI compliant, which is a big blocker for me.

Is there any way to do the same thing without the PCI compliance?

Comment: As I understand it (as a disclaimer, I don't use Paypal but other payment-gateways) that storing cards option is a different Paypal API (their rest-api vs their adaptive payments api). This question has a little bit more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426748/use-vault-with-adaptive-payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from their support. It's currently not possible to store credit card information without being PCI compliant.